# jQuery validate select box

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validation Plugin for form validation and I am not able to validate list/select box

```
<select id="select">
 <option value="-1">Choose an option</option>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Now, I want to make sure that the user selects anything but "Choose an option" (which is the default one, and has value as -1). So that it won't validate if you choose the first option. How can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validate Required Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901125/jquery-validate-required-select)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Jquery Validator custom rule](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).

A similar example is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901125/jquery-validate-required-select). The code below is from the example:

```
// add the rule here
 $.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){
  return arg != value;
 }, "Value must not equal arg.");

 // configure your validation
 $("form").validate({
  rules: {
   SelectName: { valueNotEquals: "-1" }
  },
  messages: {
   SelectName: { valueNotEquals: "Please select an item!" }
  }  
 });
```

Comment: @ down voters: why? I'm aware that "select: required" works, but this answer is also valid. It also allow you more room to customize your error message.

Answer (score 19):

Put `<option value="">Choose an option</option>` as blank rather than -1

using jquery validation

```
rules: {                      
                select: "required"
}
```

Comment: Probably it's the easiest way.

Answer (score 4):

Add this in your rule

```
select:{
  required: function(element) {
    if( $("#select").val() =='-1'){
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use the element value:

```
required: function(elm) {
    if(elm.options[elm.options.selectedIndex].value != "-1") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the value of the condition?

```
required: function(elm) {
    return (elm.options[elm.options.selectedIndex].value != "-1");
}
```

This does the same as the solution from Robin, but is much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

How can we validate for jquery ui select dropdown

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(".intselect").selectmenu();
$().ready(function() {


jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#validateregister" ).validate({
  rules: {
   firstname: {
      required: true
    },
  email: {
      required: true,
   email: true
    },
    year: {
      required: true
    }
  }
  
});
$('#validateregister').change(function() {
        if ($("#validateregister").valid()) {
            $(".go").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
  else{
    $(".go").attr("disabled","disabled");
  }
    });
});
</script>
```

```css
"sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

```html
<form id="validateregister" style="width: 300px;">
  <div> <br />
    <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" id="firstname" />
  </div>
  <div> <br />
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" />
  </div>
  <div> <br />
    <select class="form-control intselect" name="year" id="year">
      <option value="">Select year</option>
      <option value="2014">2014</option>
      <option value="2015">2015</option>
      <option value="2016">2015</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div> <br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default go" value="submit" disabled>
  </div>
</form>
```