# jquery form validation for any select value

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using jQuery validation plugin, it works fine for all fields
but, when I use it for `select` it doesn't work

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <select id="name" name="name">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value='select'>Select</option>
        <option value='abc'>ABC</option>
        <option value='xyz'>XYZ</option>    
    </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var f=$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        name:{
            required:
                 function(element) {
                     st=($(element).val() == '') || ($(element).val() == 'select');
                     return st;
                }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {required: "Please select name"}
});
```

Also, I want to `stop submition` after validation, no matter whether the form is `valid` or `not`.

**Note** I don't want to use `$.validator.addMethod`.

I've already searched

1. [jQuery select box validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896854/jquery-validate-plugin-select-list-validation)
2. [jQuery validate select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364291/jquery-validate-select-box)
3. http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/demos/jqueryvalidation/test4.html

Comment: @Zenith `<option>Select</option>` is default `empty`, isn't it?

Comment: You're right :) Can you not just use return false to stop submission?

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("#name :selected").val() == '') 
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say it's a plugin that's slightly overcomplicating an simple error check! Then again, I found the same thing you're attempting to do on the [**Developer's Github Demo page**](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html#L93).

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hAWR3/14/**

```
<script>
    $("#formsubmission").submit(function(event){ 

        /** Cache Result **/
        var tmp = $('#selectname').val();
        console.log( "Selected Name: " + tmp );

        if ( tmp == 'select' || tmp == 'Select' ) {

            /** Prevent the submission **/
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log( 'Unvalidated!' ); 

        } else {

            /** Submit as normal!! **/
            console.log( 'Validated!' );   
        }

    });
</script>

<form method="post" id="formsubmission">
    <select id="selectname" name="name">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value='select'>Select</option>
        <option value='abc'>ABC</option>
        <option value='xyz'>XYZ</option>    
    </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Note: if there's no value within the  like in your html example, it take the encased value inside the `<option></option>`'s!