# How to validate selects with jQuery validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

The following selects should be mandatory:

```
<select id="area" class="input-xlarge">
  <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>

<select multiple="multiple" id="reason" class="input-xlarge">
  <option value="001">reason001</option>
  <option value="002">reason002</option>
  <option value="003">reason003</option>
</select>
```

But the following code doesn't work:

```
$("#form").validate({
  rules: {
    "area": {
      required: true
    },
    "reason": {
      required: true
    }
```

Comment: `<select id="area" class="input-xlarge required">`...adding 'required' as a class makes jQuery Validate pickup the field and require it to have an option selected for validation out of the box. no scripting required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validate Required Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901125/jquery-validate-required-select)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, it works with first field, but doesn't work with second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select tags have no `name` attribute, which is what validation rules are based on since they are required for submittal as well as any server side validation