# Validation for Html.Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

hi i am working with a form in mvc4 using c#

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("SendPassword", "Member", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "forgot", @class = "emlfrm" }))
{
<p @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id,new SelectList(ViewBag.Users,"Id","Mem_NA"), "--Select Your Name--",string.Empty)<label id="error">       </label></p>
<p><label>Your Email</label><input type="text" class = "eml" name="email"/><label id="error">       </label></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
}
```

i am validating the email using jquery. i want to validate the dropdown list(if no item is selected show error when submit button is clicked). The values in the drop down list is added from sql table. How can i validate this.

Comment: Use jQuery validate. It has a built in method to check for email validity

Comment: @achakravarty: i want to validate that dropdownlist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901125/jquery-validate-required-select

Comment: @Coelho: i dont know what is the id of this Dropdownlist for

Comment: You can define your own rules are given in the above link by @Coelho. Normally you would use something like `element.index('Please select name') == -1`

Comment: @Parvathiiiii You don't need the id. You need an attribute "name" on the select tag