# validate select with jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a html select with a default value -1.

```
  <select id="BusinessDistrictId">
       <option value="-1">Select one...</option>
       //other options...
  </select>
```

I would like to force the users to select any option other than -1 value. 
My jquery validation rules-

```
  rules: {
         BusinessDistrictId: { required: true , min:0}
        }
```

But it's not working. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is the value -1 necessary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Validate Required Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901125/jquery-validate-required-select)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to validate this element with the jQuery Validate plugin, there are two problems with its markup...

```
<select id="BusinessDistrictId">
    <option value="-1">Select one...</option>
    //other options...
</select>
```

1)  As per the requirements of the jQuery Validate plugin, every element must have a unique `name` attribute.  When rules are declared within `.validate()`, they are identified by their `name`.  However, **no matter how rules are declared**, every element must still have a unique `name` attribute because that's how the plugin keeps track of the form elements.

2)  Your `min: 0` rule is only a workaround for a broken `required` rule.  In order to use `required: true` on a `<select>` element, you must have the `value=""` attribute on the first `<option>` element;  so  **in your case, the `required` rule will always be ignored.**  And since you have the `min: 0` rule, you are getting a similar validation result that requires an item to be selected.  Even with the `value=""` attribute on the first `option`, having both the `required` and `min` rules on a `select` element makes no logical sense.

Here is the correct code...

**HTML**:

```
<select id="BusinessDistrictId" name="BusinessDistrictId">
    <option value="">Select one...</option> <!-- first option contains value="" -->
    //other options...
</select>
```

**jQuery**:

```
rules: {
    BusinessDistrictId: {  // <-- this is the name attribute
        required: true
    }
},
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/y82dV/**

Comment: Thanks a ton. You made my concept clear. Actually, I am a new comer in web develop world. You deserve my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

adding name="BusinessDistrictId" solved my issue.