# validation of select box in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation

Hello I have developed a form where there are input box and select box. I want to give validation for both select box and input box . I am able to give validation for input box only.I am not able to give validation for select box with input box.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate();
  });
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="myform">

      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Template Name
        <span class="required"> * </span>
      </label>

      <input id="templateName" type="text" data-required="1" class="form-control" />
      </br>

      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Admission Year
        <span class="required"> * </span>
      </label>


      <input id="admissionYear" type="text" data-required="1" maxlength="4" />
      </br>

      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Select the type of eligibility
        <span class="required"> * </span>
      </label>

      <select id="reportsSelect" class="form-control" data-placeholder="Select" tabindex="1">
        <option value="0">Choose</option>
        <option value="overall">Overall</option>
        <option value="specific">Specific subject</option>
      </select>
      </br>

      <button type="button">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Where is your code? The one that does the validation of the input boxes.

Comment: Please share your javascript code ?

Comment: i have included javascript code. looking for some good suggestions

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901125/jquery-validate-required-select

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Validate Required Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901125/jquery-validate-required-select)

Answer (score 0):

Several "issues" here.

- Your labels do not reference the inputs they belong to, either by having the input inside of them, or using the `for` attribute to reference the ID of the corresponding input.
- `placeholder` on a `<select>` is meaningless
- You should use `required`, not `data-required="1"` - this lets the browser do the validation without you needing any code at all. If you have any jQuery validation, delete it. This is 2017, [you don't need it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation) :p
- A "no value" option for a `select` should be `<option value="">`. You can then add `required` to the `<select>` to require the user to select a value that isn't empty.
- Use `<input type="submit" value="Submit" />` or `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`, NOT `<button type="button">`
- I assume you have a jQuery event handler to process the form. If you use the `required` attribute (browser-native validation) then you can just listen for the `.on('submit')` event on the form - it will not fire if anything is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate();
  });
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="myform">

      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Template Name
        <span class="required"> * </span>
      </label>

      <input id="templateName" type="text" data-required="1" class="form-control" />
      </br>

      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Admission Year
        <span class="required"> </span>
      </label>


      <input id="admissionYear" type="text" data-required="1" maxlength="4" />
      </br>

      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Select the type of eligibility
        <span class="required"> * </span>
      </label>

      <select id="reportsSelect" class="form-control" data-placeholder="Select" tabindex="1">
        <option value="0">Choose</option>
        <option value="overall">Overall</option>
        <option value="specific">Specific subject</option>
      </select>
      </br>

      <button type="button">Submit</button>
    </form>
```