# Why select doesn't validate required attribute in some cases

Tags: html, validation, google-chrome

**Validation occurs:**

```
<select name="fruit" required>
  <option value="" selected> Select a fruit </option>
  <option value="apple"> Apple </option>
</select>
```

**Validation never happens:**

```
<select name="fruit" required>
  <option value="apple"> Apple </option>
  <option value="" selected> Select a fruit </option>
</select>
```

**Question**

Why HTML doesn't considers the validation of required attribute in all cases that an empty option are selected?

Comment: You should provide a jsfiddle, or embed a snippet, demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because its trying to treat the first element, since it's value is empty, as a [placeholder label option](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#placeholder-label-option), not a option to be selected, and therefore selecting it does not satisfy the "required" constraint.

Answer (score -1):

You are right as default HTML5 validator will only check the value of the first selectable if you mark the input as required.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FNP50ZBTEYOE

To modify this, you will need to use another validator and customize it by some code as well.

[jQuery Validate Required Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901125/jquery-validate-required-select)