# JQuery Validate select element not including default value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate a Select element as follows:

```
<select name="block_name" id="block-name">
 <option value="">Select Block</option>
 <option value="blockA">Block A</option>
 <option value="blockB">Block B</option>
</select>
```

which normally wouldn't be a problem if the rule was as Follows:

```
rules: {
 block_name: {
   required: true
 }
}
```

As I would just add `class="required"` to the select element. 
But I am using a function in the rule as follows:

```
rules: {
 block_name  {
  required: function(element) {
   return $("#blocks").val() >= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

which uses the following hidden field which has a data binding that determines the value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="blocks" id="blocks" value="<?php echo $row_rsCurrentUser['blocks']; ?>">
```

When using this function in the `rule` the `class="required"` does not work thus excepting the default option element `<option value="">Select Block</option>`

How can I get this to validate but not except the default option as a selection?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can add `required` property to the input box not class.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer @Shahaji Deshmukh. I am not trying to validate an input box.

Comment: Will you please look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901125/jquery-validate-required-select)? Is it same as you want?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What does `class="required"` have to do with the rule?

Comment: Sorry @Barmar I probably wasn't clear in my post. I meant I would use the `required` class instead of the rule which would validate the select element without excepting a blank value for an `option`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can define a new class rule, rather than using the built-in `class="required"`.

```
$.validator.addClassRules("required_block2", {
    required: function(element) {
        return $("#blocks").val() >= 2;
    }
});
```

Then use `class="required_block2"` on these elements.

Comment: `addClassRules` is meant for creating a compound rule.  Otherwise, you can just create a custom rule with `addMethod` and directly assign it using a class.   Ex: create a custom method called `myRule` and assign using `class=“myRule”`

Comment: @Sparky The advantage of using `addClassRules` seems to be that you can easily refer to an existing rule. While it's normally for creating rules that combine multiple rules, it extends easily to the degenerate case of one rule with a parameter like this.

Comment: Sorry for late response to this @Barmar. This works perfectly, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add all kind of validation in your function:

```js
$("#myform").validate({
  debug: true,
  rules: {
    block_name:  {
      depends: function(element) {
        var blocksIsValid = (Number($("#blocks").val()) >= 2);
        var block_nameIsValid = ($("#block_name").val() !== "");
        $('#output').text('#blocksIsValid:'+blocksIsValid+', #block_nameIsValid: '+block_nameIsValid);
        return blocksIsValid && block_nameIsValid;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
  <select name="block_name" id="block_name" required>
    <option value="">Select Block</option>
    <option value="blockA">Block A</option>
    <option value="blockB">Block B</option>
  </select>
  <input id="blocks" name="blocks" value=""/>
  <input type="submit" value="Validate"/>
  <p id="output"></p>
</form>
```

If you are not familiar with JS conditions, here are a few tips:

With `||` (same as OR) at least one of the conditions must be true;

With `&&` (same as AND) all conditions must be true.

With `!` (same as NOT) your condition will be flipped (true becomes false, false becomes true).

Read more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/conditionals

Comment: I don't understand this. The `required` rule tells it to check whether the input is empty. What sense does it make to check the input itself inside the conditional for whether the rule should be enabled?

Comment: thanks for your answer @rafaelcastrocouto. I understand what you've explained regarding the use of `||` and `&&` but I don't understand how I can utilise these to achieve validation but excluding the default option value.

Comment: Maybe you can use something like this: Condition 1 = ($("#blocks").val() >= 2) ... Condition 2 = ($("#block-name").val() !== ""). You need them both to be valid, so: Condition 1 && Condition 2. Try the code on the answer, I've updated it.

Comment: I tried that @rafaelcastrocouto but didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: "Didn't work" - what do you mean? there was an error? the validation didn't work as expected? I need more info to help you.

Comment: apologies @rafaelcastrocouto. The validation doesn't work as expected. when using your suggested rule/function setup, It simply accepts the default option element `<option value="">Select Block</option>`.

Comment: Did you remove the `option` id? Because this code `$("#block-name").val() !== ""` does not allow an empty value, but it requires the id. I'm gonna build a full demo here https://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/details/OBVaLx/

Comment: Thanks for your input to this @rafaelcastrocouto. Difficult to choose which option to go with. I went with Barmar's suggestion as I felt it was a cleaner approach.