# How to make select elements required?

Tags: html

With input of type text the attribute required is available. It is not the case for select inputs. So how to make them required ?

Comment: check if value is empty..

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287353/does-the-select-element-have-the-required-attribute

Comment: What makes you think it is not possible on `select`? According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) it is perfectly possible.

Comment: See here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp  Not working on Most browsers, use jquery validate plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make them required by using html5 attribute required just like below.

```
<select required>
<option value="">select an option</option>
<option value="value1">Value 1</option>
<option value="value2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

View Example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/88rXX/

Answer (score 4):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DvQn2/)

```
<form>
    <select required>
    <option></option><!--If this is selected require pop up will appear -->
    <option>test</option><!--If this is selected form will be submitted -->
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Please give jsfiddle demo

Answer (score 1):

Set a default value then on form submission check to see if that default value has changed.

If you're using the JQuery validation plug-in, try this [Validate select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271640/validate-select-box)

You do have to remember though that just because it's validated client side, doesn't mean you shouldn't also check server side.

Answer (score 1):

use   it based on html 5. otherwise you can use any plugin