# JS check if option in pull down menu is selected

Tags: javascript

How to check if there is any option chosen in an pull down menu as formvaldation?

```
         <div class="form-group has-warning-add has-feedback" id="div_add_eenheid">


  <select class="form-control id="add_eenheid" name="add_eenheid" onclick="validate_add()" onmousemove="validate_add()">
                <option value="">--- Selecteer eenheid ---</option>
                <option value="stuk">stuk</option>
                <option value="doos">doos</option>
                <option value="kg">kg</option>
              </select><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" id="add_eenheid_status"></span>
                </div>

function validate_add()
{
    // eenheid
    if(document.getElementById('add_eenheid').selected = true) { document.getElementById('div_add_eenheid').className = "form-group has-warning-add has-feedback"; document.getElementById('add_eenheid_status').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"; }
    else
    { document.getElementById('div_add_eenheid').className = "form-group has-success-add has-feedback"; document.getElementById('add_eenheid_status').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"; }
}
</script>
```

I have tried:

```
getElementById('add_eenheid').selected = true
getElementById('add_eenheid').value == ''
getElementById('add_eenheid').selectedIndex ==  0
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Alter ' onclick="validate_add()"' to onchange="validate_add(this.value);" then check if the value is not the empty string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271640/validate-select-box

Comment: @jeff as in document.getElementById('add_eenheid').value == '' ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validate_add(self) {
  console.log(self.value);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="validate_add(this)">
  <option value="" disabled selected>--- Selecteer eenheid ---</option>
  <option value="stuk">stuk</option>
  <option value="doos">doos</option>
  <option value="kg">kg</option>
</select>
```

- The `onchange` event will trigger whenever a new value is chosen in the dropdown.
- The `selected` tag makes sure the `--- Selecteer eenheid ---` option is the default.
- The `disabled` tag makes sure that the `--- Selecteer eenheid ---` option can never be chosen.

  - Aka: The value of the dropdown will never be the value of the `--- Selecteer eenheid ---` option.

So whenever the `onchange` event fires, you can be sure that the value of the dropdown is a valid one.